# How to read content from the browser from android app?

Tags: android, browser

I have scenario in which I have to launch the android browser from my sample application. And the browser will load a login page. Once the user enters the credentials in login page, it will redirect to a page with some data. I need to return back to my app from the android browser and I need to retrieve the content from the browser to the app.

The problem is I don know how to get back to my app with the loaded content in browser. Can anyone know how to do this in android ?

thanks,
Senthil.M

Comment: Fortunately, this is impossible, for obvious security and privacy reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to use an [embedded WebView](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html): there is no way to have the browser return the content in the page to another app.